# Canvas highlight squares on mouse move

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, grid, html5-canvas

I have a canvas with many grids on it and a text will be shown on it. I need to have user interaction with the canvas also.

I want to highlight the corresponding squares when the user drags his mouse over the canvas or clicks on it.

I am not able to select the grid which I am supposed to highlight using Javascript.
Posting the entire code -
[fiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/RemyaJ/aqqd8ftr/3/)

I tried this, but it is not working.

```
$('.canvasld').mousedown(function(e){
   let x = e.clientX -  $('.canvasld').offsetLeft,
            y = e.clientY - $('.canvasld').offsetTop,
            col = Math.floor(x /6),
            row = Math.floor(y /6);
        context.rect(x, y, 5, 5);
        //pixel['enabled'] = true;
        context.fillStyle = canvasConfig.options.enabledPixelColor;
        context.fill();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jsfiddle you linked has several problems:

First, your x and y values are `NaN`, since 
`$('.canvasld').offsetLeft)` is undefined. In JQuery, there is not `offsetLeft` property on a query.

You can use the JQuery `.offset()` method, which returns an object that has the properties `left` and `right`.

Second, your `context` and `canvasConfig` are both undefined.

Here's a snippet of the code in question with those issues corrected. I used your defaults object in place of the canvasConfig, which didn't exist:

```
// revised mousedown code
$('.canvasld').mousedown(function(e) {

  // small square size
  let squareSize = (defaults.pixelSize / 2);

  // get the x and y of the mouse
  let x = e.clientX -  $('.canvasld').offset().left;
  let y = e.clientY - $('.canvasld').offset().top;

  // get the grid coordinates
  let col = Math.floor(x / squareSize);
  let row = Math.floor(y / squareSize);

  // get the canvas context
  let context = $('.canvasld')[0].getContext('2d');

  // check if the square falls into the smaller grid
  if(col > 0 && row > 0 && col % 2 > 0 && row % 2 > 0) {
    // draw the rectangle, converting the grid coordinates back 
    // into pixel coordinates
    context.rect(col * squareSize, row * squareSize, squareSize, squareSize);
    context.fillStyle = defaults.enabledPixelColor;
    context.fill();
  }

});
```

Hope I could help! :-)

Comment: Thankyou for your help, but when I pasted this my fiddle, it is not highlighting the grid I click on and I dont want it to highlight on the black part, it should highlight just on the grey part(ie. the square).How can I get the square I want to highlight?

Comment: You can check if the row and column are > 0 and if the row and column are both odd. If all these conditions pass, then you draw the yellow square.

Comment: If I was able to help, please upvote my answer! I am trying to gain reputation as I am a new user.

Comment: Ok I will upvote but now it looks like this, it is highlighting the black area also :( https://jsfiddle.net/aqqd8ftr/13/.

Comment: Ah — I finally realized what you meant! My mistake! Let me take a look.

Comment: Turns out it was due to my misunderstanding of what "pixelSize" meant. I thought that the small squares were this width, but they seem to be double that width. I've updated my code in my answer to address this.

Comment: Just a small doubt , how can I use this same code on mouse drag?

Comment: The exact same way! You can put this into a function, which can be called on movedown and mouse drag (not sure of the proper event name).